# Asp.net Web API objects definitions

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am working on the asp.net web api where i have to return back objects in json. With respect to making a better approach and easy for (android/ios)mobile developer to consume these Web APIs and parse json objects, what is best approach for making these objects definitions remain shared amongst webapi project and mobile project, so that if we have to change any property then it can easily be reflected on both projects in a better way. It would be great if someone explains it in detail.

Comment: What kind of application is the consumer?

Comment: @k4rlsson consumer application will be of type android/ios built in xamarin studio

Answer (score 2):

There is no such sync method as you are asking.

On your WebAPI server side you'll define the objects and then return them in your API methods. JSON serialization will be automatically handled by the framework, using your serialization engine of choice (i.e. JSON.NET). Remember that with WebAPI you don't decide the output format server side, you just return a response containing the object(s) and then the framework reads the HTTP HEADERS of the request to determine whether the client asked for JSON or XML and then returns what was asked.

The best thing you can do is define a clear API with nice conventions and keep it documented, and if you change anything have the documentation reflect the changes. Avoid making breaking changes, and if you really must, deprecate a property or an object for at least a couple of versions before removing it.

That's the way all public API work anyway.